# WebGL, three.js. Проблемы с заполением оперативной памяти при загрузке текстур

Tags: webgl, javascript, three.js

Пишу просмотрщик панорам, в общем у меня есть функция, она грузит текстурки добавляет к сцене и добавляет в массив, так она жрет на каждую панораму(15мб картинка) где-то по 150мб оперативы и после перехода от одной панорамы к другой он просто занимает еще 150мб, и так, если их штук 10, получается 150+150+150....потом страница ломается

```
function actionRerender(num) {

loaded = false;
d.querySelector('.loader').style.display = 'block';
container.style.opacity = 0;

var object = globalData[num],
sphereMaterial;

if (sphereMaterialCache[object.name] === undefined) {
sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(globalData[num].texture),
side: THREE.BackSide
});
sphereMaterialCache[object.name] = sphereMaterial;
}

mesh.material = sphereMaterialCache[object.name];
}
```

Если я меняю так, чтобы не добавлялось в массив и каждый раз зануляю переменную sphereMaterial, он продолжает занимать оперативку, но при повторном открытии одной и той же панорамы так же занимает еще 150мб

```
function actionRerender(num) {

loaded = false;
d.querySelector('.loader').style.display = 'block';
container.style.opacity = 0;

var object = globalData[num],
sphereMaterial;
sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(globalData[num].texture),
side: THREE.BackSide
});

mesh.material = sphereMaterial;
sphereMaterial = null;
}
```

Что может изменить, чтобы предыдущая панорама как-то удалялась из памяти и не занимала оперативку?

http://vk.com/doc13433889_301525253 вот ссылка на него, на всякий случай..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй
sphereMaterial.map = null;